# Dynamically Building Buttons

Tags: .net, vb.net, button

I am using VB.Net.
I have a list of 13 buttons. The names of these buttons are constructed through a combination of 3 different variables.

I need to disable all these buttons. I do not want to iterate through each button to disable them. I would like to dynamically call these buttons in a loop and then disable them. Something like this;

```
For Count = 1 To 13
    PeriodRoomID = ("R" & ds.Tables("sqlSpecRoomRequest").Rows(i).Item(3) & Count)
    PeriodRoomID.Enabled = False
    PeriodRoomID.Backcolor = Color.Gray
Next
```

The problem is that once creating the variable PeriodRoomID, I can't address it as a button because;

- That would mean there are two buttons with the same name.
- PeriodRoomID is a string and therefore can't be enabled because that makes no sense.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Please don't just throw "[VB.Net]" into your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) method.

```
dim cntrl() as Control
For Count = 1 To 13 
    PeriodRoomID = ("R" & ds.Tables("sqlSpecRoomRequest").Rows(i).Item(3) & Count) 
    cntrl = Me.Controls.Find(PeriodRoomID,True)
    cntrl(0).Enabled = False
    cntrl(0).Backcolor = Color.Gray
Next
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU MARK!

Works like a charm.